# is there a way to check if the email and password edit text are filled before excecuting the login button intent?

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent

I am new to android. i have created a login page with email and password editTexts and a login button. how can i check if the email and password is filled before executing the login button intent? and how is the login button conditional intent declared?

here is my xml code

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/emailEt"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/passwordEt"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/loginBtn"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="login"


        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordEt" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are lot of ways that this can be handled. A simple google search could have helped you out.

The most simple way is to set OnClickListener() for the Login Button. The listener method will be called when the button is clicked.

Inside the method, you can check if the Edittext field is empty using the *TextUtils.isEmpty("TEXT INSIDE EDITEXT")* method.

The text inside the edit text can be read using the *getText()* method.

Please have a look at the below code for reference.

```
    public OnClickListener onLoginClick = new OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        EditText emailField = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id. emailEt);
        String email = emailField.getText().toString()

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
        {
           // Show error here
        }
        else
        {
          // Do the necessary action here.
        }

    }
};
```

Similarly, add a check for the password field.

In the XML file, set the listener to the Login button like this.

```
android:onClick="onLoginClick"
```

Comment: i think this is what OP was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
yourEditext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Here you can store email into variable before clicking button
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: probably don't have to use a textChangeListener just to see if there is text or not

Comment: there's nothing written like that @a_local_nobody

Comment: `how can i check if the email and password is filled before executing` this means they just want to see if there IS text before doing something, not constantly watch the text as it changes :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can user `myEditText.addTextChangedListener()` when user is Typing you will get the the email and password

```
emailEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Here you can store email into variable before clicking button
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: probably don't have to use a textChangeListener just to see if there is text or not

Comment: then i think we have to get value when needed only

Comment: `check if the email and password edit text are filled before...` sounds like OP just wants to check if there's text in there or not